# How To Download images & Store in SDcard in Blackberry using phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to download an image from a server and store it on a SD card and then display it on a blackberry 10.

But I can't download the file.

This is my code:

```
fileTransfer.download(
    "http://smartphone.thnt.vn/VietGames/GhepTranhTu/IOS/update/" + anhup[i], 
    "file:///SDCard/downloads/" + anhup[i],
    function (entry) {
        sa = entry.fullPath;
        alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);

        if(i < anhup.length - 1) {
            doDownload(i + 1);
        } else {
            alert("download done");
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

get sd card directory path from this:-

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFSData, fail);

function gotFSData(fileSystem) {     
   console.log(fileSystem.root);                
   fileSystem.root.getDirectory("download", 
                                {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
                                gotFileEntrywriter, 
                                fail);                              
}
```

Comment: Thanks for respond when i use that, the folder is "local:///pesident/download", i wnat to save to file:///SDCard/downloads.